# Extends HashMap with custom fields for JSON converter

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

This is my class which extends HashMap because there are lots of dynamic fields in the response JSON but education and employments are fixed and I want those should be mapped with PeopleEducation and PeopleEmployment clasess

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "_education", "_employment" })
public class People extends HashMap<String, Object> implements Map<String, Object> {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@JsonProperty("_education")
private List<PeopleEducation> Education = new ArrayList<PeopleEducation>();
@JsonProperty("_employment")
private List<PeopleEmployment> Employment = new ArrayList<PeopleEmployment>();
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 *
 * @return The Education
 */
@JsonProperty("_education")
public List<PeopleEducation> getEducation() {
    return Education;
}

/**
 *
 * @param Education
 *            The _education
 */
@JsonProperty("_education")
public void setEducation(List<PeopleEducation> Education) {
    this.Education = Education;
}

/**
 *
 * @return The Employment
 */
@JsonProperty("_employment")
public List<PeopleEmployment> getEmployment() {
    return Employment;
}

/**
 *
 * @param Employment
 *            The _employment
 */
@JsonProperty("_employment")
public void setEmployment(List<PeopleEmployment> Employment) {
    this.Employment = Employment;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

So is it possible to map these fields to specific class using Spring Rest Template

```
ResponseEntity<People> response = restClient.getResource(url, headerMap,People.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it will get matched automatically if it is valid JSON.
If the response is in String format you have to use [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html)
 to parse and convert it to the Object.

For better understanding, can you also post your JSON string.